# In sysctl.conf settings, what is the difference between 'all' & 'default'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, kernel

In context of  sysctl.conf settings, 
what is the difference between (`all` vs. `default`) like `net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route` & `net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route`  in sysctl settings ?

If I added `all` values, is it necessary to add `default` as well ?

---

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90443/sysctl-proc-sys-net-ipv46-conf-whats-the-difference-between-all-defau).

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to [Symantec and google](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/linux-firewall-related-proc-entries):

When you change variables in the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all` directory, the variable for **all interfaces and default** will be changed as well.

When you change variables in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default`, **all future interfaces will have the value you specify**.

This should only affect machines that can add interfaces at run time, such as laptops with PCMCIA cards, or machines that create new interfaces via VPNs or PPP, for example.